# Simple file compression in C

Tags: c, file, compression

I'm new to programming with C, and I need somewhere that I can read up on file compression in C. I only need a simple recognised method. An example would help but mostly somewhere I can read to understand.

Answer (score 5):

maybe a good starting point is RLE which is extremely simple but not so trivial to implement. Check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Answer (score 2):

The first method I learned in school is Huffman Encoding.  Here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Here is a link to a C implementation:  http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/huffman-code